# CGPA Calculator in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Im making a cgpa calculator in android studio but app crash on following line always.`gpa=Double.parseDouble(marks_et.getText().toString());`

**complete code is here.**

```
public class CgpaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 GridLayout DynamicEditTextHolder;
 EditText edtNoCreate,marks_et,cr_et,cgpa_ET;
 Button btnCreate,CalculateGPA;
 TextView course;
double cgpa = 0,gpa,sumgpa = 0;
int i,length;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cgpa);

    DynamicEditTextHolder = findViewById(R.id.DynamicEditTextHolder);
    edtNoCreate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNoCreate);
    cgpa_ET=findViewById(R.id.cgpa_ET);
    btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
    CalculateGPA=findViewById(R.id.CalculateGPA);
    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()>0) {
                try {
                    DynamicEditTextHolder.removeAllViews();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 length = Integer.parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString());

                for ( i=1;i<=length;i++){

                    course=new TextView(CgpaActivity.this);
                    course.setId(i);
                    course.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    course.setX(10);
                   // course.setX(ALIGN_BOUNDS);
                   // course.setRowOrderPreserved(false);
                    course.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                    course.setText("Course"+(i));
                    DynamicEditTextHolder.addView(course,new GridLayout.LayoutParams());

                    marks_et = new EditText(CgpaActivity.this);
                    marks_et.setId(i);

                    marks_et.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    marks_et.setHint("marks ");
                    marks_et.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                    DynamicEditTextHolder.addView(marks_et,new GridLayout.LayoutParams());
                    gpa=Double.parseDouble(marks_et.getText().toString());
                    sumgpa += gpa;
                }


            }
        }

    });

    CalculateGPA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             {
                cgpa = sumgpa / length;
                cgpa_ET.setText(String.valueOf(cgpa));
            }

}

    });
```

}
}

Comment: Add the error log...

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
        at app.twilight.uafcgpacalculator.CgpaActivity$1.onClick(CgpaActivity.java:67)

Comment: last line in above code